# Is it possible to pick a random operator?

Tags: python

I have some code here, on a simple arithmetic test which stores results on a txt file. However, I am experiencing an issue on trying to get the question to have a random operator each time. In this part of the code:

```
operators = random.choice[+, -, *, /]
```

I am getting a syntax error. Here is my whole code:

```
import random
def arthematictest():
  name = input("whats your name?: ")
  operators = random.choice[+, -, *, /]
  a = random.randint(1, 100)
  b = random.randint(1, 100)
  question1 = int(input(f"whats {a} {operators} {b}?")
  answer1 = (f"{a} {operators} {b}
  feedback = open("feedback.txt", "a")
  feedback.write(name)
  feedback.write(" ")
  feedback.write("passed")
  if question1 == answer1:
    print("correct")
  else:
    feedback = open("feedback.txt", "a")
    feedback.write(name)
    feedback.write(" ")
    feedback.write("failed")
    print("incorrect")
```

How would I edit my code so each time it is ran, there is a different operator? I would also like the operators to be part of the calculation, not just to be printed out.

Comment: you can use [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) from Python's standard library

Comment: Side note, but good job using f-strings. Not enough tutorials teach that as the preferred practice, so it's nice to see newcomers starting out with good practices.

Comment: Do you want to use `operator` just for printing the question or also to calculate `answer1`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I would like the operators to calculate answer1 also @mcsoini

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with that line. First, `random.choice` is a function, so its arguments should be enclosed in parentheses. Second, `+` and the other operators are not valid list elements in and of themselves. If you want the operators as text, enclose them in quotes.

```
operators = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/'])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to control the range of operands and only allow for integer answer, you should compute your result as either an addition or multiplication of integers. For subtraction and divisions, swap the result with the first operand to formulate the question.

You can use random.choice to pick a string symbol as the random operator. This will make it easier to prepare the answer and formulate the question.

```
import random

Q    = 0                                   # question number
good = 0                                   # count of good answers
while Q < 10:                              # ask 10 questions
    operands = range(1,13)                 # possible operands in rande 1...12
    operator = random.choice("+-x/")       # random operator
    a,b = random.choices(operands,k=2)     # random operands
    c   = a+b if operator in "+-" else a*b # perform base operation
    if c in operands: continue             # want a non-trivial question
    if operator in "-/" : a,c = c,a        # result as 1st operand for - and /

    Q += 1
    answer = input(f"Q{Q}: what is {a} {operator} {b} ? ")
    if answer == str(c):
        print("correct")
        good += 1
    else:
        print(f"incorrect, {a} {operator} {b} is {c}")
    print()

print("Score:",good,"/",Q)
```

Sample run:

```
Q1: what is 2 x 11 ? 22
correct

Q2: what is 8 + 12 ? 20
correct

Q3: what is 13 - 10 ? 3
correct

Q4: what is 13 - 8 ? 7
incorrect, 13 - 8 is 5

Q5: what is 12 x 4 ? 48
correct

Q6: what is 49 / 7 ? six
incorrect, 49 / 7 is 7

Q7: what is 14 - 5 ? 9
correct

Q8: what is 18 / 3 ? 6
correct

Q9: what is 12 + 5 ? 17
correct

Q10: what is 14 - 6 ? 8
correct

Score: 8 / 10
```

*If you want to allow negatives and zero as operands, you simply have to change the range: `operands = range(-12,13)`*

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example which you can adapt to your code. It prints the operator and uses the corresponding function from the `operator` module to calculate the result:

```
import random
from operator import add, truediv, mul, sub

a, b = 10, 4
for _ in range(10):
    operator_string, operator = random.choice([("+", add), ("/", truediv),
                                               ("*", mul), ("-", sub)])
    
    answer1 = operator(a, b)
    print(f"{a} {operator_string} {b} = {answer1}")

# Out:
10 * 4 = 40
10 + 4 = 14
10 - 4 = 6
10 * 4 = 40
10 + 4 = 14
10 / 4 = 2.5
10 + 4 = 14
10 + 4 = 14
10 / 4 = 2.5
10 / 4 = 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could choose the operator like this:

```
  operator = random.choice('+-*/')
```

And apply it like this:

```
  answer1 = eval(f"{a} {operator} {b}")
```

(`eval` is unsafe for user-supplied strings, but since you're building the string yourself here, it's alright)